# 文字コードSJISのファイルデータを文字コードUTF-8のデータベース(Oracle)に文字化けしないでプログラムで格納できますか？

Tags: c#, oracle, 文字化け, shift-jis

文字コードがSJISのファイルデータを読み込んで、文字コードがUTF-8のOracleデータベースのテーブルにデータを登録したいです。プログラムをC#で作成する際、文字コードの差異による問題がありましたらご教示頂きたく、よろしくお願い致します。

C#ではファイルをSJISで読み込んで、そのままDBへの登録処理をするだけで、プログラムやデータベースが文字コードの差異を吸収してくれるとありがたいのですが。

**実行環境**
Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016
.NET Framework 4.6.2
Oracle 12.2

Comment: C#での読み込み時は文字化けしておりませんでしょうか？またOracleにInsertして初めて文字化けを確認されましたでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確認はまだしておりません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C#の`string`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string)はUnicodeと定められています。つまり、外部とやり取りする際には常にエンコーディングの変換が行われます。Shift-JISのファイルを読むのであれば読み込みの際にエンコーディングを指定しますし、Oracleと接続する際にはOracle側とエンコーディングの整合が取られます。

後は、各々を正しく設定するだけの問題となります。

Answer (score 0):

文字コードを指定してデータを読み込む

```vb
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser parserData = new TextFieldParser(yourFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift_JIS"));
string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
```